# Grails spring security core, how to set principal manually

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Hi im trying to make facebook's login in a grails app, the problem I have is that when the user is logged in facebook, spring security core doesn't recognize him, how can I set the user's principal manually?
I can look for the user object but i don't know how to set it in order to get a true user when i call getAuthenticatedUser() (now it returns a null object)

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 4):

Cannot say anything regarding facebook, but Spring Security has a [SecurityContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) that can be used to manipulate the authentication (and therefore the principal) like this:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder as SCH
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken


....
def securityContext = SCH.context
def principal = <whatever you use as principal>
def credentials = <...>
securityContext.authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials)
```

Maybe you'll need to use a different implementation of the [Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) interface as the one used in the example.